# External RAID5 volume activity lights constantly flashing only when screen is locked

Tags: macos, command-line, security, raid

I have an external SoftRAID RAID5 volume that constantly and vigorously flashes when my computer has gone to the lock screen. As soon as I hit a key to bring up the login screen it stops.

It's rather annoying as it lights up the entire room at night. And I would also like to understand what is accessing it while the screen is locked but doesn't when it's not locked.

I have my Photos.app library on this volume so I presume it has something to do with background tasks - but seriously how much work is there to do when I don't have iCloud storage on for this library (except for shared albums), and I haven't added new photos in over a week. This happens consistently for hours and days and weeks and months.

I have run a command while logged in to see what is actively attached to the volume while I am not logged out, but logged in.

```
lsof -w +c0 +D /Volumes/Godzilla | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sort -u | column -t

COMMAND                          PID
cloudphotod                      1838
com.apple.CloudPhotosConfigurat  5879
photoanalysisd                   1806
photolibraryd                    1177
```

Is there anything else I can check to see which of these or other processes is actually communicating when the lock screen is active? Like see the stats on activity and timestamps?

Comment: Have you checked the drive is actually spun up & being accessed & not just complaining it lost its host?

Comment: If it's actually in use (not idle flashing), then it's probably just some sort of indexing process. For example, both the photos app and spotlight will run indexing tasks while your session is inactive/locked. Depending on the model, you might be able to disable the activity LEDs (or just tape over them)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - I actually keep two rolls of plastic electrical tape, precisely for this reason. One white, one black. The white you can apply in successive layers until you can just tell the light is on, the black for total darkness.

Comment: @Tetsujin, the drive is spun up. I have two external enclosures only the one with `Photo Library.photoslibrary` is being accessed like this.